# Progress dialog stuck on fragment transition

Tags: android, android-fragments, progressdialog

I would like to show progress dialog while my fragment is loading.
I am converting the size of some images in the fragment, so preparing the fragment takes some time. But after I show the progress dialog, it doesn't spin, it just stuck until fragment is getting ready.

Here is my example codes.
Code for creating fragment:

```
//show progress bar
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
//Create fragment
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
setFragment(myFragment).commit();
```

In my fragment code:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the app "freezes" or gets stuck, this is because you are performing a long-running operation, such as reducing image sizes, on the main or **UI** thread. In order to prevent this, perform any long-running operations on a separate thread with `AsyncTask`. An example of this [can be shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example).